# Discord.js Reaction not collecting awaitReactions

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm having problems getting my reaction collector to collect reactions it just times out any ideas would be appreciated.

```
        message.awaitReactions((reaction, user) => user.id == message.author.id && (reaction.emoji.name == '1️⃣' || reaction.emoji.name == '2️⃣'),
        { max: 1, time: 30000 }).then(collected => {
          
                if (collected.first().emoji.name == '1️⃣') {
             let roll1 = util.randomroll(1, 101)
                if(roll1 > 50){
                   
                    bot.db.add(`${message.author.id}.balance`, amount);
                    message.channel.send(bot.embed(`**${quidteam1t}** WON!!! YOU GAINED **${amount}**`));

                }else{
                    bot.db.add(`${message.author.id}.balance`) -= amount;
                    message.channel.send(bot.embed(`**${quidteam2t}** Won and you lost **$${amount}** better luck next time!`))
                }


                }
        }).catch(collected => {
            message.reply('you didnt react');
        });
   console.log(`${message.author.username} used QuidditchBet to start a betting event!`)
    





    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to constantly ask for emojis first and then use it in your code? What i mean is : `const reaction1Emoji = '1️⃣'` and `const reaction2Emoji = '2️⃣'`  and then replace where `emoji.name` with `reaction1Emoji` and `reaction2Emoji` !